# evaluate postfix expression after converting it from an infix expression

Tags: java, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I have this code that convert infix expression to postfix expression after that I want to evaluate the expression and find the value so what I did is asked the user to enter an expression in eg. A+B*C+D way then I convert it using a method after that I ask the user to input values for A,B,C and D so I can evaluate the expression, when the user enters the values I place them in an string array and try to evaluate it but I am stuck here and have tried many ways to do the evaluation but no luck! Here is my code:

```
public class Main {
    private Stack stack = new Stack();
    char symbol;
    String postfix = "";
    String prefix;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public char prefixLetterOrOprand(char ch) {
        if (Character.isLetter(ch))
            prefix = ch + prefix;
        else {
            while (!isEmpty() && charValue(ch) <= charValue((char) stack.peek()))
                prefix = stack.pop() + prefix;
            stack.push(ch);
        }
        return ch;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public String toPostfix(String infix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < infix.length(); ++i) {
            symbol = infix.charAt(i);
            isLetterOrOprand(symbol);
        }
        while (!isEmpty())
            postfix = postfix + stack.pop();
        return postfix;
    }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public int evaluate(String expression, int[] value) {
    String a = convertExpressionToValues(expression, value);
    int sum = 0;
    Stack<Character> operand = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Character> operator = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= expression.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(expression.charAt(i)) == true) {
            operand.push(a.charAt(i));
            System.out.println("Letters: " + operand.peek());
        } else {
            if (operator.isEmpty()) {
                operator.push(expression.charAt(i));
            }
            if (!operator.isEmpty() && charValue(expression.charAt(i)) >= charValue(operator.peek())) {
                operator.push(expression.charAt(i));
                sum = Integer.parseInt(a);
            }
            System.out.println("Digits: " + operator.peek());
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

private String convertExpressionToValues(String expression, int[] value) {
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder(expression);        
    a.replace(a.indexOf("A"), a.indexOf("A") + 1, Integer.toString(value[0]));
    a.replace(a.indexOf("B"), a.indexOf("B") + 1, Integer.toString(value[1]));
    a.replace(a.indexOf("C"), a.indexOf("C") + 1, Integer.toString(value[2]));
    a.replace(a.indexOf("D"), a.indexOf("D") + 1, Integer.toString(value[3]));
    return a.toString();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public char isLetterOrOprand(char ch) {
        if (Character.isLetter(ch))
            postfix = postfix + ch;
        else {
            while (!isEmpty() && charValue(ch) <= charValue((char) stack.peek()))
                postfix = postfix + stack.pop();
            stack.push(ch);
        }
        return ch;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public int charValue(char ch) {
        if (ch == '+' || ch == '-')
            return 1;
        else if (ch == '*' || ch == '/')
            return 2;
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return stack.size() == 0;
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter a value");
        String value = scan.next();
        Main main = new Main();
        System.out.println("Postfix Value: " + main.toPostfix(value));
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Prefix Value: " + main.toPrefix(value));

        System.out.println("Enter A Value For A: ");
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter A Value For B: ");
        int b = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter A Value For C: ");
        int c = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter A Value For D: ");
        int d = scan.nextInt();
        int[] values = { a, b, c, d };
        main.evaluate(values);
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you save the values as numbers, not strings, since you want to do arithmetic with them. You also should use a `Map` instead of an array so that you can look up the values by name.

Comment: I have tried to to make it Stack<String> to achive my goal but my charValue(char ch) method does not support that so If there is any better suggestions please advice.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `charValue()` method?

Comment: @code-apprentice And how can I find what is the operand passed if im using numbers?

Comment: Will the infix expression which you convert to postfix have any constants or just variables?

Comment: @code-apprentice it checks if the char is equal to + or - returns 1, * or  / returns 2, else will return 0 which donate a character so I can find which operand have a higher priority

Comment: No the user will be asked to fill in constant after entering a expression of variables

Comment: I see what `charValue()` does. (Your comment just repeated the code ijn English). This doesn't tell me its purpose. Why does it do this? What is it used for?

Comment: it get the stack.pop() value and compare to the current value if they are both operands it will check which has a higher priority or to check if its a letter and will either place it in a stack or append it to a string depending on the case

Comment: So `charValue()` is used to determine the order of operations. Is that right? In other words, it helps you decide to do multiplication and division before addition and subtraction.

Comment: yes, you can see what its used for in the isLetterOrOprand(char ch)  method

Comment: I'm asking you to let you explain and help you understand it yourself better.

Comment: ok I see i appreciate your help

Comment: If you can explain your code to me so that I understand it, then that means you actually understand it yourself. (Hopefully)

Comment: I see a problem. You enter the expression in `main()` but then you don't do anything with it.

Comment: I have tried to change the way im implementing the charValue() method but could not find a better solution

Comment: I am getting the postfix expression right after that I am trying to ask the user to add values for the variables and convert it to a string array but here i miss the operands and dont know what to do

Comment: oic...my eyes skipped over the part where you convert the expression to postfix.

Comment: p.s. I suggest you change the variable name `value` to `expression`. Do you see why this makes more sense?

Comment: yeah sorry my bad

Comment: I have been trying so many ways and got out of ideas on what to do to make it evaluate the expression

Comment: okay, I edited my answer with some tips. Hopefully it will give you some ideas to help you head in the right direction.

Comment: @code-apprentice sir I have edited my evaluate() method and now it accepts the expression as a string and an int[] of the values as arguments, and the logic of the method is written but now am struggling with replacing the constants (A,B,C,D) with the values can you help please with that

Comment: Do not replace the variables directly in the expression. Instead, substitute the variables with their values as you evaluate the entire expression.

Comment: The operands should be Stack<Integer> so that you can do the arithmetic.

Comment: Note that the result is not just a sum. You need to check the operator to determine what to do.

Comment: @code-apprentice I changed my stack to Integer and I checked the operator before adding the value to the sum but I am getting a wrong answer so can you explain more about what you said above in substituting  the variables with the values?

Comment: please show the most recent version of your code

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
public int evaluate(int[] value) {
    String a = Arrays.toString(value);
    System.out.println("PREFIDXSS:: " + toPostfix(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Here `value` is the array of values that were entered by the user. When you convert this array to a String, you get something like `"[1, 2, 3, 4]"`. Note that this is **not** an infix expression, so sending this String to `toPostfix()` will not work since that method expects the String to be a proper infix expression.

You have some of the right idea. You need to do something similar to your current `toPostfix()`. However, you are missing a very important piece of information: **the expression to evaluate**.

You have two options here:

1. When you convert from infix to postfix, you can save some representation of the expression that can be used later for evaluation.
2. You can write a modified form of your `toPostfix()` function that takes **two** parameters: an infix expression and an array of values for the variables. The algorithm for this new method is very similar to what you have. The primary difference is that you will need a `Stack<Integer>` so that you can do the actual calculations. You will also need to perform the operations when you encounter the operator symbols in the infix operation. The final result will be a number rather than a String.

Comment: for the first option I have a string that represent the expression which is postfix string, after calling the toPostfix method the postfix string has the expression

Comment: @KhaledJamal to use the postfix string, you will have to parse it one character at a time.